# How to use Compare Validator for dates if the date is split in several fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, comparevalidator

I am finishing a form in C#, and I would like to validate the data entry. I have seen numerous posts about validating with "CompareValidator". That's fine and clear.

I just would like to ask about a twist: I have the date in one field, result of using the AjaxControlToolkit Calendar Extender. You can retrieve it as:

```
DateField.Text;
```

Then I have the hour in another field of the form, using MKB Time Select package from NuGet.

```
TimeSelector1.Hour + ":" + TimeSelector1.Minute
```

is the value I want to use.

So the user has been filling the form, and picked a date from the date field, and an hour from the time selector. I want to check if the date and time that the user selects in these fields, is at least 24 hours greater than the current time, so it means the validator needs to use these two different fields to grab the initial data.

I am a bit confused about how would I get started about that.

Basically, the validator should show the warning if

```
DateField.Text + " " + TimeSelector1.Hour + ":" + TimeSelector1.Minute
```

is greater than

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(24)
```

But I don't see clear how to tell the validator to validate this sort of statements, rather than the plain content on the fields.

Comment: It's not really clear to me as to what you are trying to do here. Could you not parse your DateField.Text and your TimeSelector values into a DateTime object and then compare it?

Comment: I didn't think of that! That could work for my purpose. Still, I am not sure about the best way to create a data object by using a field that returns a date such as dd/mm/YYYY and then the other two time values returning simply HH and mm. All the information I am finding is for VB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided, you should be able to parse your values into a DateTime object.

```
string dateString = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}:00", DateField.Text, TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute);
DateTime selectedDateTime = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out selectedDateTime))
{
    if (selectedDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(24))
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I must add that rather than Compare Validator, I decided to use this function with the custom validator. I found it easier in some way.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should parse your date and time strings into DateTime object then compare it with DateTime.Now.AddHours(24)

```
    var inputDate = "20150606 10:12";
    DateTime date;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        //datetime has invalid format
    }
    else
    {
        if(date > DateTime.Now.AddHours(24))
        {
            //show warning
        }
    }
```